# How to determine whether an array object has a value, and then return the array of objects with this value,

Tags: javascript

How to determine whether an array object has a value, and then return the array of objects with this value. Because I'm a novice, Similar to fuzzy search, give an example：

```
const menu = [
  {
    title: "one",
    secondLevel:{
      name:"hellobye",
      children: [{name: "hello"}, {name: "bye"}],
   }
 },
  {
    title: "two",
    secondLevel:{
      name:"level",
      children: [{name: "good"}, {name: "night"}],
   }
 }
]
```

1. Assume input "go", the result should be:

```
menu = [
   {
    title: "two",
    secondLevel:{
      name:"level",
      children: [{name: "good"}, {name: "night"}],
   }
 }
]
```

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#some

Answer (score 2):

If that object structure is consistent, then you can just do a `filter` with `some` and `includes`:

```js
const menu=[{title:"one",secondLevel:{name:"hellobye",children:[{name:"hello"},{name:"bye"}],}},{title:"two",secondLevel:{name:"level",children:[{name:"good"},{name:"night"}],}}];

const filterBy = toFilter => {
  return menu.filter(({ secondLevel }) => secondLevel.children.some(({ name }) => name.includes(toFilter)));
};

console.log(filterBy("go"));
console.log(filterBy("ll"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```